# Python 3 Socket Receive Data

Tags: python, sockets

I am working with python sockets and although I have read everything I can find on stackoverflow, regarding the socket.recv byte stream, I still have a few questions I hope some of you can answer.

So I have this line:

```
chunk = s.recv(1024)
```

I receive the following packet: `'\x12\x03\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x23\x45\x34\x56'`

I need to get bytes at index `1` & `2` ('\x03\x10') and convert the 2-byte data to an integer .. which should be 784.

What is the best way to handle this?

In addition, what is the best way to remove a portion of the chunk data and pass it into a function? I.E. I need to remove bytes at index 7 - 9 and pass that string of 3 bytes into a function.

Comment: Do you have to deal with a byte stream? The socket module, at least in python 2.7, allows strings to be sent without the headache of serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#module-struct) module:

```
import struct
pkt = b'\x12\x03\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x23\x45\x34\x56'
i = struct.unpack_from('>h', pkt, 1)[0]

>>> print i
784
```

The format string `'>h'` means that the data has big endian byte order (`>`) and to treat the data as a short 2-byte integer (`h`). There is also an unsigned variety denoted by `H`.

To grab a substring of the data use slicing:

```
>>> idx = 7
>>> length = 3
>>> pkt[idx:idx+length]
b'#E4'
```

and pass it to a function:

```
>>> func(pkt[idx:idx+length])
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting substrings out of a larger string is simple; for example, given:

```
>>> thestring = 'this is a test'
```

If I want bytes 1 and 2, and I can ask for:

```
>>> thestring[1:3]
'hi'
```

In your example, once you have the two bytes of interest:

```
>>> chunk = '\x12\x03\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x23\x45\x34\x56'
>>> data = chunk[1:3]
```

You can use the `struct` module to unpack those into a single integer:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('H', data)
(4099,)
```

That assumes native byte order.  You can explicitly request big endian like this:

```
>>> struct.unpack('>H', data)
(784,)
```

Read the `struct` documentation for more information.  Note that `H` (used here) means "unsigned short", while `h` (used in another answer) means "signed short", and which one is appropriate depends on your application.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Is there a way to print the byte array and prevent the ascii while maintaining the "\x" format? Doing `print(chunk)` works great for non-ascii characters, but when the byte is printable, I get the ascii character.

I tried using `print(binascii.hexlify(chunk))` but the formatting makes troubleshooting long byte arrays impossible. I am so used to seeing "\x" that is all I want to see in my print statements.

I was hoping Python had some easy way to keep the hex data in the print output?

Thanks again!

Comment: You could do something like `print ''.join('\\x%02x'% ord(x) for x in chunk)`, I guess.  There may be something simpler.